# IPv4 link-local address in Linux

Tags: ip

I remember that in Windows XP, when DHCP client did not receive an IPv4 address from DHCP server, the host assigned itself an IPv4 link-local address from 169.254.0.0/16. However, I have never seen the Linux host behave the same way. Does this depend on DHCP client implementation? I use ISC dhclient version 4.1. Or when does Linux use IPv4 link-local addresses?

Comment: Try installing [avahi-autoipd](http://linux.die.net/man/8/avahi-autoipd).

Answer (score 1):

(I am sorry, but I can't comment yet - so here it goes):

I think you need the "leases" option configured in your dhclient for such occasions.

See: [dhclient(8)](http://linux.die.net/man/8/dhclient)

> Old leases are kept around in case the DHCP server is unavailable  when dhclient  is  first  invoked  (generally during the initial system boot process).   In that event, old leases  from  the  dhclient.leases  file which have not yet expired are tested, and if they are determined to be valid, they are used until  either  they  expire  or  the  DHCP  server becomes available.
>
> A  mobile host which may sometimes need to access a network on which
> no DHCP server exists may be preloaded with a lease for a fixed
> address on that network.   When all attempts to contact a DHCP server
> have failed, dhclient will try to validate the static lease,  and  if
> it  succeeds, will use that lease until it is restarted.

Answer (score 0):

You could fake this feature using a static lease in dhcp.conf but it will not behave properly if another system already uses that ip address. Normally when selecting a link local address the host will run tests to validate that no one is already using the address and if a conflict is detected it will attempt to select another address until it finds one that is available.

You will need to look into the avahi-autoipd package if you want to implement this feature under linux. It is not part of the dhcp client.